# WebGL: INVALID_VALUE: texImage2D: no canvas in three.js

Tags: three.js

I followed a procedural planet example from `https://github.com/brunosimon/lab/blob/master/experiments/procedural-planet/index.html`, the original three.js version is old.

The general idea of the code is simple, firstly generate a facted sphere from six box geometries, and then generate six textures from the gradient canvas, at last generate the material from these generated textures.

the main code about generating material

```
      function  generate_material()
    {
        var maps      = generate_maps();
        //console.log(maps.textures);
        var    materials = [];
        // Each face
        for( var i = 0; i < 6; i++ )
            materials.push( get_shader_material( maps.textures[ i ], maps.bumps[ i ] ) );
            //materials.push(   new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: makeCanvasTexture()})  );
        return materials;
    }
```

function  generate_maps ()
{
var textures   = [],
bumps      = [],
materials  = [],
resolution = 1024;

```
        // Each face
        for(var i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            var texture        = new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget( resolution, resolution, { minFilter : THREE.LinearFilter, magFilter : THREE.LinearFilter, format : THREE.RGBFormat } ),
                texture_camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera( - resolution / 2, resolution / 2, resolution / 2, - resolution / 2, -100, 100 ),
                texture_scene  = new THREE.Scene(),
                geometry       = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry( resolution, resolution ),
                material       = new get_texture_shader_material( i, seed, options.clouds.distortion ),
                plane          = new THREE.Mesh( geometry,material);
            materials.push( material );
            texture_camera.position.z = 10;
            plane.position.z          = - 10;
            texture_scene.add(plane);
            renderer.render( texture_scene, texture_camera );

            /**/
            // Retrieve buffer
            var buffer = new Uint8Array( resolution * resolution * 4 ),
                gl     = renderer.getContext();
            gl.readPixels( 0, 0, resolution, resolution, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer );
            textures.push( texture );
            bumps.push( {
                image :
                {
                    data   : buffer,
                    height : resolution,
                    width  : resolution
                }
            } );
            
            
        }

        // Return
        return {
            textures  : textures,
            bumps     : bumps,
            smaterials : materials,
        };
```

}

```
function get_shader_material ( texture_map, bump_map )
        { //
            var vertexShader   =  document.getElementById( 'planet-vertex-shader' ).textContent,
                fragmentShader =  document.getElementById( 'planet-fragment-shader' ).textContent,
                uniforms       = generate_uniforms( texture_map );

                    if(textures.water){
        
        }else{
          console.log('no water')
        }

        uniforms.tWaterGradient =
        {
            type  : 't',
            value : textures.water.texture
        };

        uniforms.tGroundGradient =
        {
            type  : 't',
            value : textures.ground.texture
        };

        uniforms.tIceGradient =
        {
            type  : 't',
            value : textures.ice.texture
        };

        return new THREE.ShaderMaterial( {
            uniforms       : uniforms,
            vertexShader   : vertexShader,
            fragmentShader : fragmentShader,
            transparent    : true
        } );
    }

function get_texture_shader_material ( index, seed, clouds_distortion )
        {
            var vertexShader   =  document.getElementById( 'planet-texture-vertex-shader' ).textContent,
                fragmentShader =  document.getElementById( 'planet-texture-fragment-shader' ).textContent,
            uniforms       =
            {
                index :
                {
                    type  : 'i',
                    value : index
                },
                fCloudsDistortion :
                {
                    type : 'f',
                    value : clouds_distortion
                },
                v3Seed :
                {
                    type  : 'v3',
                    value : seed
                }
            };

        return new THREE.ShaderMaterial( {
            uniforms       : uniforms,
            vertexShader   : vertexShader,
            fragmentShader : fragmentShader,
            transparent    : true,
            depthWrite     : false
        } );
    }
```

I reused most of the code however got some problem with the material part, the code example I made is seen here -  https://jsfiddle.net/ufjqcht6/86/

```
three.module.js?3179:19902 WebGL: INVALID_VALUE: texImage2D: no canvas
texImage2D @ three.module.js?3179:19902
GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glGenerateMipmap: Can not generate mips ERROR GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glGenerateMipmap: Can not generate mips
RENDER WARNING: texture bound to texture unit 1 is not renderable. It might be non-power-of-2 or have incompatible texture filtering (maybe)?
RENDER WARNING: texture bound to texture unit 2 is not renderable. It might be non-power-of-2 or have incompatible texture filtering (maybe)?
```

the code example can be seen here, where the issues can be only seen from the chrome 's developer 's console.

I debugged the code but I can't identify whether the problem coming from the shader's code or the js's code ? and how to solve it

Answer (score 0):

> I debugged the code but I can't identify whether the problem coming from the shader's code or the js's code ?

The problem is the way you are using `Object.assign()` in your code. For the second and third texture, you overwrite the `style` property so it does not has a definition for `width` and `height` anymore. `Gradient_Texture.init()` will then assign `undefined` to the canvas's dimensions which results in the respective WebGL error.

Fixing the `Object.assign()` statements solves the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/L21jz07k/